# Set checkbox as checked by default in a metabox

Tags: custom-field, metabox

OK here I go again..lol sorry. And yes I have looked all over for an answer however the code I am using is different and I can't wrap my head around it.

So I got this from ***GenerateWP.com*** again I asked for assistance and never got an answer. here it is:

```
class TP_Primo_Featured_Image_Options_Custom_Meta_Box {
    public function __construct() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action('load-post.php',array($this,'init_metabox'));
            add_action('load-post-new.php',array($this,'init_metabox'));
        }
    }

    public function init_metabox() {
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this,'add_metabox'));
        add_action('save_post', array($this,'save_metabox'), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function add_metabox() {
        add_meta_box(
            'tp-primo-featured-image-options',
            __( 'Featured Image Options', 'tp-primo' ),
            array( $this, 'render_metaboxrender_tp_primo_featured_image_options_metabox' ),
            array( 'post', 'page' ),
            'side',
            'default'
        );
    }

    public function render_metaboxrender_tp_primo_featured_image_options_metabox( $post ) {

        // Retrieve an existing value from the database.
        $tp_primo_show_below_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tp_primo_show_below_title',true);
        $tp_primo_show_above_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tp_primo_show_above_title',true);
        $tp_primo_set_page_header = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tp_primo_set_page_header',true);
        $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay',true);
        $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax',true);
        $tp_primo_page_header_height = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tp_primo_page_header_height', true );

        // Set default values.
        if( empty( $tp_primo_show_below_title ) ) $tp_primo_show_below_title = 'checked';
        if( empty( $tp_primo_page_header_height ) ) $tp_primo_page_header_height = '';

        // Form fields.
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_show_below_title" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_show_below_title . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_show_below_title, 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Show Below Title', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_show_above_title" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_show_above_title . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_show_above_title, 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Show Above Title', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_set_page_header" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_set_page_header . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_set_page_header, 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Set as Page Header', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay, 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Page Header: Title Overlay', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
        echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax, 'checked', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Page Header: Title Overlay/Parrallax', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
        echo '<label for="tp_primo_page_header_height" class="tp_primo_page_header_height_label">' . __('Page Header Height', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="tp_primo_page_header_height" name="tp_primo_page_header_height" class="tp_primo_page_header_height_field" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( '', 'tp-primo' ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $tp_primo_page_header_height ) . '">';
        echo '<p class="fi description">' . __( 'Use PX, %, REM, EM and VH based values.', 'tp-primo' ) . '</p>';
    }

    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

        // Sanitize user input.
        $tp_primo_new_show_below_title = isset($_POST['tp_primo_show_below_title']) ? 'checked' : '';
        $tp_primo_new_show_above_title = isset($_POST['tp_primo_show_above_title']) ? 'checked' : '';
        $tp_primo_new_set_page_header = isset($_POST['tp_primo_set_page_header']) ? 'checked' : '';
        $tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay = isset($_POST['tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay']) ? 'checked' : '';
        $tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay_parallax = isset($_POST[ 'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax']) ? 'checked' : '';
        $tp_primo_new_page_header_height = isset($_POST['tp_primo_page_header_height' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'tp_primo_page_header_height' ] ) : '';

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta($post_id,'tp_primo_show_below_title',$tp_primo_new_show_below_title);
        update_post_meta($post_id,'tp_primo_show_above_title',$tp_primo_new_show_above_title);
        update_post_meta($post_id,'tp_primo_set_page_header',$tp_primo_new_set_page_header);
        update_post_meta($post_id,'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay',$tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay);
        update_post_meta($post_id,'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax',$tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay_parallax);
        update_post_meta( $post_id,'tp_primo_page_header_height',$tp_primo_new_page_header_height);
    }
}
new TP_Primo_Featured_Image_Options_Custom_Meta_Box;
```

As you can see, I tried adding `if( empty( $tp_primo_show_below_title ) ) $tp_primo_show_below_title = 'checked';` under the section that says `// Set default values.`

***"Show Below Title"*** is checked by default (which is what I want...woohoo) but if I uncheck it and check ***"Show Above Title"*** and hit update it shows **"Show Below Title"** **AND** ***"Show Above Title"*** checked...booooo!

I need to set "Show Below Title" (`$tp_primo_show_below_title`) as the default. I just can't seem to get it. What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I stated I got this code from GenerateWP.com from their metabox generator. You add the info you want and it builds the metabox for you. The only thing is, they do not show you how to display the info when you use certain things like radio buttons or dropdowns. And I guess when you ask for help they get very offended and say "This is not fair your trying to get me to code for you"...hence the reason I came here looking for help.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving unchecked checkbox values as empty strings:

```
public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

    // Sanitize user input.
    $tp_primo_new_show_below_title = isset($_POST['tp_primo_show_below_title']) ? 'checked' : '';
    ...

}
```

So when you fetch the saved unchecked value and then check for `if(empty(...))`, it returns true and sets `'checked'` as the default value because [`empty(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value.
>   Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Since `get_post_meta` also returns an empty string if no value is found, the only way to distinguish is by saving a separate value for unchecked boxes. So instead of saving `'checked'` and `''` as the meta values, it would be better to use `1` and `0`. This will also take less space in the database.

Edit:

Change the functions as follows:

```
public function render_metaboxrender_tp_primo_featured_image_options_metabox( $post ) {

    // Retrieve an existing value from the database.

    ...

    // Set default values.
    // Only non-existent checkbox values will be empty strings, as we are saving '1's and '0's.
    // We cannot use the empty function since empty('0') will also return true.
    if( $tp_primo_show_below_title == '' ) $tp_primo_show_below_title = '1'; //checked by default
    if( $tp_primo_page_header_height == '' ) $tp_primo_page_header_height = '0'; //unchecked by default

    // Form fields.
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_show_below_title" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_show_below_title . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_show_below_title, '1', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Show Below Title', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_show_above_title" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_show_above_title . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_show_above_title, '1', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Show Above Title', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_set_page_header" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_set_page_header . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_set_page_header, '1', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Set as Page Header', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay, '1', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Page Header: Title Overlay', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax" class="tp_primo_featured_image_locations_field" value="' . $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax . '" ' . checked( $tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax, '1', false ) . '> ' . __( 'Page Header: Title Overlay/Parrallax', 'tp-primo' ) . '</label></p>';

    ...

}

public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

    // Sanitize user input.
    $tp_primo_new_show_below_title = isset($_POST['tp_primo_show_below_title']) ? '1' : '0';
    $tp_primo_new_show_above_title = isset($_POST['tp_primo_show_above_title']) ? '1' : '0';
    $tp_primo_new_set_page_header = isset($_POST['tp_primo_set_page_header']) ? '1' : '0';
    $tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay = isset($_POST['tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay']) ? '1' : '0';
    $tp_primo_new_page_header_title_overlay_parallax = isset($_POST[ 'tp_primo_page_header_title_overlay_parallax']) ? '1' : '0';

    ...

    // Update the meta field in the database.

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

so to get the desired effect I would do:

`if( empty( $tp_primo_show_below_title ) ) $tp_primo_show_below_title = '1';` ?

This is all confusing to me, sorry.

Comment: yes and don't forget to change the parameters for the `checked` function call

Comment: OK I have no idea what you just said...lol I'm new to all this so I have no idea what I am doing. Mind showing me?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show all changed lines.